# What do “and of” meaning in the following sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

What do “and of” meaning in the following sentence?

> Recognition of a particular asset or liability is appropriate if it provides not only relevant information, but also a faithful representation of that asset or liability **and of** any resulting income, expenses or changes in equity.

Comment: *a faithful representation of that asset or liability **and [a faithful representation] of** any resulting income, expenses or changes in equity*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is saying that recognition of an asset or liability is appropriate if it is "a faithful representation" of two things:

- **of** that asset or liability;
- **and of** any resulting income, expenses or changes in equity.

It isn't always necessary to repeat a preposition in such a way, for example:

> I went to the cinema **with** John and **with** David.

You wouldn't normally say this, you'd just say:

> I went to the cinema with John and David.

Your example sounds like an excerpt from a legal document. Legal language is always about removing any trace of ambiguity, I suspect that is the reason for repeating "of" in yours.

Comment: It seems like I am asking a stupid question, but it's so hard for a non-English speaker to read legal documents. By the way, thank you for your great answer.

Comment: @ClementLeung Not stupid at all - legal documents are difficult for native speakers to read!